# Resources to learn MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy

Can you recommend resources to learn msdeploy? Books, blogs or other formats welcome.

Bonus points will be awarded for information focused at deploying to IIS 6 and inserting the SVN revision number into the packaged files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is lots of reference documentation for command line use of the Web Deploy tool on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568996%28WS.10%29.aspx). For practical how-to’s [IIS.NET](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deploy/) is the place to go.

Unfortunately, there's very little documentation on how to customize the deployment package during from the build. So, I've posted [an article](http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html) on my blog about my own findings while preping a project for deployment with Web Deploy recently.

It contains links to other articles as well as how to implement common deployment requirements, including some handling of version / build numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I've blogged about how to use MSDeploy to deploy a web application to IIS from TeamCity.

Web Deploy (MS Deploy) from TeamCity - http://www.geekytidbits.com/web-deploy-ms-deploy-from-teamcity/

Answer (score 1):

Sayed Hashimi is my go to guy for all things MSBuild and MSDeploy:
[Hashimi's Blog](http://sedodream.com/SearchView.aspx?q=msdeploy)

and a number of interesting articles here:[Vishal Joshi's Blog](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.ie/)